# Activity becomes black while calling the run time permissions

Tags: android, android-activity, android-contacts, onactivityresult, runtime-permissions

I want to call run time permissions to read contacts on click of some view. So I checking if app has the permissions and if not requesting for the permissions. But When the request dialog appears the activity gets black and gets finished if allow or deny is clicked on dialog. When I debug the app, it dose not go to the onRequestPermissionsResult method after clicking allow or deny.

Also I am calling the contact Intent if permissions are accepted. I want to show these in the same activity as a list of selected contacts. So for this I have a list and added contacts to the list onActivitResult method.

But for this also if I select some contact from contacts, the activity gets finished. It dose not go to the onActivityResult method.

```
public class PlanEventActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener,
        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    private static final int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS = 100;
    private boolean mHoursMode, updateEvent, subevent,permissionsAccepted;
    RelativeLayout chooseEvent, time, date;
    EditText eventName, chooseEventText, timeTextView, dateTextView;
    private RelativeLayout parent;
    static final int CUSTOM_DIALOG_ID = 0;
    private String mEventId, mMainEventId;
    ListView dialog_ListView;
    private Intent mIntent;
    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    private TextView title;
    private ImageView addOrganizer;
    private ArrayList<Organizers> mSelectedContacts;
    private RecyclerViewAdapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView mContactsList;
    private ArrayList<Event> subEventArrayList;
    public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs1";
    private Button mSubmit;
    private String mEventType, mEventName, mEventDate, mEventTime, mOraganizerName, mOrganizerPhone,
            mOrganizersId, mOrganizersEmail, mOrganizersLastName, mOrganizerFirstName, userName;
    private Event mEvent;
    private static final int RESULT_PICK_CONTACT = 10;
    private Organizers mOrganizers;
    private ImageButton add;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_plan_event);

        mIntent = getIntent();

        subEventArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        setUpUI();

        mContactsList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        mAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this, mSelectedContacts);
        mContactsList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        ((RecyclerViewAdapter) mAdapter).setMode(Attributes.Mode.Single);


    }

    public void setUpUI() {

        addOrganizer = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.addOrganizer);

        mContactsList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.selectedContactsList);

        mSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);

        add = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.addButton);

        mSelectedContacts = new ArrayList<>();

        updateEvent = mIntent.getBooleanExtra("updateEvent", false);

        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

                permissionsAccepted = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("permission1",false);

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS}, PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
                    //After this point you wait for callback in onRequestPermissionsResult(int, String[], int[]) overriden method
                }
                else if (permissionsAccepted && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

                    Intent contactPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI);
                    startActivityForResult(contactPickerIntent, RESULT_PICK_CONTACT);
                }
                else {

                    Intent contactPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI);
                    startActivityForResult(contactPickerIntent, RESULT_PICK_CONTACT);

                }
            }
        });

        addOrganizer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

                permissionsAccepted = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("permission1",false);


                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    Log.d("request","Request permission is called");

                    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS}, PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);

                }
                else if (permissionsAccepted && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

                    Intent contactPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI);
                    startActivityForResult(contactPickerIntent, RESULT_PICK_CONTACT);
                }
                else {

                    Intent contactPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI);
                    startActivityForResult(contactPickerIntent, RESULT_PICK_CONTACT);

                }

            }
        });

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePickerDialog view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        String date = dayOfMonth + "/" + (++monthOfYear) + "/" + year;
        dateTextView.setText(date);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {

        if(requestCode == PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS)
        {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.

                permissionsAccepted = true;

                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("permission1", permissionsAccepted);
                editor.commit();


                Intent contactPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(contactPickerIntent, RESULT_PICK_CONTACT);

            }

        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // check whether the result is ok
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Check for the request code, we might be usign multiple startActivityForReslut
            switch (requestCode) {
                case RESULT_PICK_CONTACT:

                    mOrganizers = new Organizers();
                    contactPicked(data);
                    mOrganizers.setFName(mOrganizerFirstName);
                    mOrganizers.setMobile(mOrganizerPhone);
                    mOrganizers.setEmail(mOrganizersEmail);
                    mOrganizers.setId(mOrganizersId);
                    mOrganizers.setLName(mOrganizersLastName);

                    mSelectedContacts.add(mOrganizers);

                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    if (mSelectedContacts.size() != 0) {

                        addOrganizer.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        mContactsList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        add.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    } else {

                        addOrganizer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    }
                    break;
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Failed to pick contact");
        }
    }

    private void contactPicked(Intent data) {
        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {

            // getData() method will have the Content Uri of the selected contact
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            //Query the content uri
            cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            // column index of the phone number
            int phoneIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
            // column index of the contact name
            int nameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);

            int contactIdIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID);

            mOrganizerPhone = cursor.getString(phoneIndex);
            mOraganizerName = cursor.getString(nameIndex);
            mOrganizersId = cursor.getString(contactIdIndex);

            final String[] projection = new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA, // use
                    // Email.ADDRESS
                    // for API-Level
                    // 11+
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE};

            Cursor emailCursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, projection,
                    ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(mOrganizersId)}, null);

            if (emailCursor.moveToFirst()) {
                final int contactEmailColumnIndex = emailCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA);

                while (!emailCursor.isAfterLast()) {
                    mOrganizersEmail = emailCursor.getString(contactEmailColumnIndex) + ";";
                    emailCursor.moveToNext();
                }
            }

            String[] parts = mOraganizerName.split(" ", 2);
            mOrganizerFirstName = parts[0]; // 004
            mOrganizersLastName = parts[1];

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void resetOrganizer(Context context) {

        addOrganizer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mContactsList.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

    }

    public void showAlert(String alert,PlanEventActivity activity) {

        parent = (RelativeLayout)activity.findViewById(R.id.parentPanel);

        Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(parent, alert, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
        snackbar.show();

    }

    }

}
```

Strange thing the same code was working fine before. For the older version. I also tried to copy the same activity of older version to the new version, but still it dose not work.

Not getting whats wrong.

Can anyone help please? Thank you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you don't have `android:noHistory=true` attribute entered in the activity declaration in `AndroidMenifest.xml`.

Comment: oh yes.. but I want this activity not to keep any history. @Keval Patel

Comment: You can cal `finish()` where ever you're leaving the activity or starting new activity (using `startActivity()` or `startActivityForResult()`). That will remove your activity from back stack.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS}, PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);`

with `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS}, PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);`